# Dictionary/LUT implementation in C

Tags: c, lookup-tables

I have 500 frames for which I have stored the length of each frame in an array as the frames are in ascending order.

```
const char header_length = {23,34, 45, 12, 23,56,......,2,4};
```

Here frame 1 is of length 23 bytes, frame 2 is of length 34 bytes.
Now when I am requested frame with header 4 I would have to reply with frame with header 7, frame with header 8 would require a reply frame with header 60. The co-relation is a constant, header 4 frame will always reply header 7 frame. So I need a look up table sort of implementation here. I plan to implement this using a multidimensional array. Although is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: The first two sentences are making sense. The rest are...well, totally out of a context.

Comment: Just find a RB tree C implementation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. To simplify consider there are 4 frames 1,2,3,4 with length 23, 34 ,45 12. When I receive frame 1 I reply with frame 2, when I receive frame 3 i reply with frame 4, lets consider the other frame replies as 0 for now. The LUT will be an array whose index+1 is the frame number. In position 1 I will store the length and in position 2 the reply frame. So in our case of 4 frames a dictionary implementation would look like[23:2,34:0,45:4,12:0] . Hope this simplifies the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering based on OP's comment above, otherwise OP's question just does not make any sense.

Assuming that the maximum frame size is limited by a considerably small `N`, then it may be better to just keep another array as the following,

```
const char header_length[] = {23,34, 45, 12, 23,56,......,2,4};
const int to_be_replied[N+1] = {...,0,...,2,...,0,...,4,...}; /* fill remaining */
/* here are their positions        @12   @23    @34  @45  */
```

and use the following during the reply.

```
int frame_num, reply_frame_num;
frame_num = get_frame_number(); /* some function */
reply_frame_num = to_be_replied[header_length[frame_num]];
```